# How can I fetch rows with most recent timestamp for each key value

Tags: php, mysql

table structure: id|emp_id|latitude|longitude|timestamp

I have a table of current_location data. Each row has a id,emp_id, a timestamp, and other fields. I want to select a single row with latest timestamp for each emp_id, including some of the other fields.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Please rephrase the question for reability, using some ",." might help. Some lines of `create table ...` and `insert into ...` help making a decent [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use sub query

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM emp_locations order by timestamp desc) as temp_table group by emp_id;
```

Comment: SELECT emp_id,timestamp,`latitude`,`longitude` 
FROM current_location_of_emp s1
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM current_location_of_emp s2 WHERE s1.emp_id = s2.emp_id)
GROUP BY emp_id